# React. Cómo enviar un dato de un input a otro componente?

Tags: reactjs

soy nueva en `react` y estoy realizado una pequeña práctica que consiste en lo siguiente: tengo 2 componentes, en el principal o Home (el nombre de mi componente) tengo un pequeño `form` que me envía un dato, en el `onSubmit` de este `form` ya se redirecciona a mi otro componente (Info), pero además de que redireccione necesito enviar el dato hacia este componente y reflejarlo, si me pueden ayudar con esto muchas gracias de antemano. Utilizo `react-router-dom` para la redirección

este es mi componente Home:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class index extends Component {
   constructor(props){
   super(props)
     this.state = {
       name: ''
     }
    
     this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this); 
     this.handleNameSubmit = this.handleNameSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   handleNameChange(event){
    this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state)
   } 

   handleNameSubmit(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log(this.state.name)
     window.location = "../Info"
   }

  render(){
    return (
     <div>
       <form onSubmit={this.handleNameSubmit}>
         <label>Name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
         <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
       </form>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

export default index
```

mi componente Info aún esta vacío

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class index extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no es recomendable el uso de `window.location` en React ya que contas con recursos o librerías que son más recomendables para las buenas prácticas como [**react-router-dom**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom).

Podrías utilizar las siguientes formas:

#### Caso 1: [React Context API](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (recomendable):

Dentro de (por ejemplo) `src/context` crear un archivo `context.js` con el siguiente contenido:

```js
import React from "react";

const valoresPorDefecto = {
  name: "",
  setName: () => {}
};
const contexto = React.createContext(valoresPorDefecto);
export default contexto;
```

En el mismo directorio crear otro elemento contenedor para realizar las funciones, por ejemplo `ContenedorContexto.js` (como buena práctica, para aumentar la escalabilidad de tu aplicación):

```js
import React from "react";
import Context from "./context";

const valoresPorDefecto = {
  name: "",
  setName: name => (valoresPorDefecto.name = name)
};

const ContenedorContexto = props => (
  <Context.Provider value={valoresPorDefecto}>
    {props.children}
  </Context.Provider>
);

export default ContenedorContexto;
```

Tu código, ejemplo **Componente1**:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Context from "../../context/context";

const Component1 = props => {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  const [redireccion, setRedireccion] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const handleNameChange = e => setName(e.target.value);
  const handleNameSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    context.setName(name);
    setRedireccion(true);
  };

  return redireccion ? (
    <Redirect to="/Componente2" />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleNameSubmit}>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Component1;
```

Para que `<Redirect />` funcione es necesario que en componente padre tengas:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ContenedorContexto from "./context/ContenedorContexto";
import Componente1 from "./components/Component1";
import Componente2 from "./components/Component2";

function App() {
  return (
    <ContenedorContexto>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/componente1" component={Componente1} />
          <Route path="/componente2" component={Componente2} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ContenedorContexto>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Luego en tu segundo componente, "Info", llamésmole **Componente2**:

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Context from "../../context/context";

const Component2 = props => {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Ejemplo: {context.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component2;
```

## [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-tereshkova-p01fj?fontsize=14)

#### Caso 2: window.location

En el caso de que sigas prefiriendo utilizar `window.location` puedes pasar el parámetro así: `window.location = "../Info?name=" + this.state.name`.

#### Caso 3: [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Redirect/to-object) (en aplicaciones pequeñas)

O bien utilizar una combinación de ambos casos así, lo cual reduce un poco la escalabilidad en grandes aplicaciones:

```js
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "../Info",
    search: "?name=" + this.state.name
  }}
/>
```

Y luego leerlo con `this.props.location.name`.

Bueno, espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos.

> **Edit 1:** Refactoricé el código para que utilice componentes funcionales y hooks.
>
> **Edit 2:** Agregué un Demo funcional en CodeSandbox al final del primer caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder :) , utilice el caso nro 1 el cual usted me recomienda me fue muy útil pero hasta cierto punto, cuando realiza la redirrecion a mi componente Info (que es donde se trata de visualizar el dato enviado) me da el siguiente error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null ",  adicional a esto también me di cuenta que en el componente Home (donde esta el form) se importa el componente ContenedorContext pero no lo utiliza en ninguna parte de código, si me puede ayudar con este inconveniente gracias de antemano

Comment: @FGutierrez, mi error. Ya lo edité, agregué el componente `ContenedorContexto` al componente padre que contiene el enrutador. Como puedes ver para que envuelva a todo.

Comment: Ahora cuando trato de escribir en el input me sale este error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setName' of undefined y se refiere a la linea 14  del componente Home  handleNameChange(event){
> 14 |  this.context.setName(event.target.value);
  15 |  console.log(this.context.name)
  16 | }

Comment: Creo que el problema estaría en:
1. El estado `{redireccion: false}`, agregarle otro `name: ''`.
2. El input `<input value={this.context.name}...` a `<input value={this.state.name}`. De todos modos, en la respuesta refactoricé tu código para que sea más legible y corto (**Edit 1**).

Comment: Lo cambie como me indica en el Edit 1 y me da los siguiente errores: Line 6:  React Hook "useContext" is called in function "index" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 7:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "index" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function    react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 8:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "index" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function    react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: @FGutierrez agregué un demo funcional (**Edit 2**) en CodeSandbox que muestra en funcionamiento la solución.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! , ya pude identificar los detalles que tenia y me funciona, ademas que aprendí algo nuevo :D

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás usando `react-router-dom` deberías poder usar el objeto `history` y hacer algo así:

```
   handleNameSubmit(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log(this.context.name)
     this.setState({redireccion: true})


     this.props.history.push('/ruta', contenido);
   }
```

Sino está disponible en el componente porque no sea un hijo directo de Router, pueden hacer lo siguiente para conectarlo:

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

P.D. Has nombrado la clase como `index`. Para que sea reconocida como una clase de React tienes que poner la primera letra Mayúscula `Index`